# IF statement in Google Sheets needs to search until closer to the greatest number

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a calculator which looks at minutes, this is what I have so far, the trouble is all of the arguments are true, I need for this formula to look for the highest number and match it to that.

So if D5>120 then return 3, right now it returns 2 as condition also true, please help.

=IFS(D5>60,2,TRUE,D5>120,3,TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

`IF` and `IFS` returns the value of the first match, put the conditions in descending order:

```
=IFS(D5>120,3,D5>60,2)
```